# how to get insane bump working in gimp installed in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gimp

i've followed this http://registry.gimp.org/node/28638 post and done everything without missing a single step, and i've did it many a times,but i don't actually get the option of insane bump in filters>map, can anyone suggest me any other way to get it working

Comment: What version of gimp are you running? where did you place the extracted `gimp-plugin-insanebump` file, exactly?

Comment: yes, i can add the screenshot

Comment: @steeldriver and here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5sD2PI0YoRvbGpzVTVlanlCUXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this file have the executable bit (chmod u+x) set?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the plugin using Kubuntu 15.04. Adding the executable bit didn't help. Starting gimp from the console shows:

*kindprozess »/home/myuser/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/gimp-plugin-insanebump« konnte nicht ausgeführt werden (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)*

means:

*childprocess »../gimp-plugin-insanebump« couldn't be executed (File or directory not found)*

I think maybe a library used by InsaneBump is missing. Thats why I tried to compile the plugin, but I get another error (also mentioned in the comments here: https://code.google.com/p/gimp-plugin-insanebump/wiki/BuildingFedora20Version). At least it looks like this project isn't updated anymore.

If you checkout the source, you'll find "./gimp-plugin-insanebump/fedora/bin/gimp-plugin-insanebump-Fedora20-1.0.7.tar.gz". This version is working for me, just copy it to the plug-in folder.